# Bad rendering for borders of circles on a game in Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a little game. Here you can see a zoom of black and white circles which represent the points of 2 players. Blue circles are the potential hits to play :

[image]

My issue is that borders of blue circles are badly rendered : the white border is not well drawn and I can't understand why whereas for white and black circles, borders are thin and well displayed.

Here is the code that I have used in JavaScript:

```
function showPlayableHits(HitCurrent, isShowing) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
   if (HitCurrent.arrayPlayable[i][j] == 'playable') {
    if (isShowing)
     drawPiece(i, j, HitCurrent.playableColor, HitCurrent.playableBorderColor);
    else
     deleteHit(i, j);
   }
  }
}
```

with :

```
function drawPiece(ix, iy, colorIn, colorBorder) {
 // Coordinates on canvas : 
 // x horizontal increasing from left to right
 // y vertical increasing from top to bottom
 var k = ix*width/8 + width/16;
 var l = iy*height/8 + height/16;
 // Draw piece
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(k, l, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = colorIn;
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 1;
 context.strokeStyle = colorBorder;
 context.stroke();
}
```

I don't know where this bad rendering could come from. Maybe this a stuff with 0.5 pixels shifting like we often see concerning the drawing with Canvas but I am not sure of that.

**UPDATE 1:** I realized there is another issue : all circles on image seem to be shifted slightly on the left towards the boxes (1 pixel or 0.5 pixel ?) in which there are : maybe this will merit another post on SO.

**UPDATE 2:** so let's get in details : the main board is contained into main div :

```
 <div id="main-wrapper">
              <div id="othello-wrapper">
                 <canvas id="othello-canvas" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
              </div>
              <div id="score-zone-wrapper">
                 <table id="score-zone">
                    <tr>
                       <td id="score-zone-white" colspan="2" style="padding: 3px;">White Score</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td id="score-white"></td>
                       <td align="center" style="float: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 20px;">
                          <svg height="48" width="48">
                             <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="23" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" />
                          </svg>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td id="score-zone-black" colspan="2" style="padding: 5px;">Black Score</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td id="score-black"></td>
                       <td align="center" style="float: right; margin-top: 5px; padding-right: 20px;">
                          <svg height="48" width="48">
                             <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="23" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="black" />
                          </svg>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
              </div>
```

with following CSS for `othello-wrapper` id :

```
#othello-wrapper {
    border: 5px solid black;
    cursor: crosshair;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 481px;
    height: 481px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

and for drawing dimensions (see `function drawPiece(ix, iy, colorIn, colorBorder` above) :

```
// Size of canvas
var width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;
// Radius of each piece
var radius = 0.9 * width/16;
```

Does issue come from the `(481,481)` size for `div` and `(480,480)` size for canvas ?

Comment: -@jaydeep patel what do you mean by "provide your SVG image" ?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel it's not about SVGs man!

Comment: How do I get the blue circles in your game?

Comment: -@Mathyn ok, sorry, I forgot to tell it You click on "start game" and after "show playable hits"

Comment: Have you tried drawing each circle at the same coordinates (say 0, 0)? Do they all have a nice border in such a scenario?

Comment: looks like it's relative to colors. no clue how its engine is working, but that's the only possibility I've come up with. maybe you can turn that around with some `rgba` tricks. if u had a snippet or fiddle would be easier to peak.

Comment: It appears that only the outer edge of the white border is aliased - the inner edge is anti-aliased just fine. Perhaps there are multiple "playable" circles stacked on top of each other? [here's a fiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/chazsolo/ks32tmc0/2/).

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are calling `showPlayableHits`? Perhaps you are calling it more than once inadvertently?

Comment: -@chazsolo the entire code is available on http://31.207.34.24/game/game.js . I have checked it and it soesn't seem to be a problem of multiple calls

Comment: Understood, but questions seeking debugging help should include all relevant code _within the question itself_, preferentially within a code snippet as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help future readers who come across your question. If your external code changes, it doesn't help anyone. I'm looking over it now.

Comment: My best guess is that the call `showPlayableHits` in `computHit` is the problem (line 539). You need to be clearing the blue circles every time before you draw them. If you but a breakpoint in that function in your web-developer tools you'll see that it is called more than once.

Comment: @chazsolo thanks, the issue was at line 687 : I have to call `deleteHit` in all cases, not only if isShowing is true.

Comment: If you want I can write up an answer for you, or you can make one yourself and mark it accepted. Glad you found it!

Comment: @chazsolo . yes you can write an answer, I will accept it. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with stacked elements that have anti-aliasing, in this case the border of the blue circle. When multiple anti-aliased edges are drawn on top of each other the opacities are added and will cause the edge to appear aliased.

In the function to determine whether to render the playable hits or not:

```
function showPlayableHits(HitCurrent, isShowing) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (HitCurrent.arrayPlayable[i][j] == 'playable') {
        if (isShowing)
          drawPiece(i, j, HitCurrent.playableColor, HitCurrent.playableBorderColor);
        else
          deleteHit(i, j);
      }
    }
}
```

you are only deleting the "hits" if the `isShowing` flag is false. You need to call this function on every iteration of the draw call, otherwise `drawPiece` is called and multiple circles are drawn on top of each other.